# Como muestro los datos de una tabla introduciendo su dni?

Tags: java

Estoy empezando a usar Swing en intellij y quiero saber como puedo traer datos de una tabla de la base de datos y me los muestre en los JTextField. En la base de datos tengo dos tablas que es alumno y modulo.

```
public class Alumno {
    private String dni;
    private String nombre;
    private String localidad;

    public Alumno(String dni, String nombre, String localidad) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }
}
```

tengo sus clases creadas también en el programa por que he estado leyendo y es la mejor forma.

```
public class Modulo {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private int horas;

    public Modulo(int id, String nombre, int horas) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.horas = horas;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getHoras() {
        return horas;
    }

    public void setHoras(int horas) {
        this.horas = horas;
    }
}
```

Tengo tambien este JDialog.

```
public class VerAlumnos extends JDialog {
    private JPanel WinVerAlum;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JButton btnBuscar;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JTextField textField3;
    private JTextField textField4;
    private JTextField textField5;
    private JCheckBox programacionCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox entornosDeDesarrolloCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox lenguajeDeMarcasCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox basesDeDatosCheckBox;
    private JCheckBox sistemasInformaticosCheckBox;
    private JButton btnElimina;
    private JButton buttonOK;
    private JButton buttonCancel;

    public VerAlumnos() {
        setContentPane(WinVerAlum);
        setModal(true);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonOK);
        // call onCancel() when cross is clicked
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                onCancel();
            }
        });

        // call onCancel() on ESCAPE
        WinVerAlum.registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onCancel();
            }
        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    }

    private void onOK() {
        // add your code here
        dispose();
    }

    private void onCancel() {
        // add your code here if necessary
        dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VerAlumnos dialog = new VerAlumnos();
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que quiero es poner el dni y cuando le de al botón de buscar se me rellene los datos incluidos los checkBox. No soy capaz de hacerlo si me podrían ayudar por favor!

Comment: Quiero hacerlo de la mejor forma posible. Ojala me ayuden muchas gracias!

Comment: no termino de entender cuál es el problema con el que te encuentras. el mismo botón te ofrece agregar distintos listeners a los eventos. cuando se le haga click, deberías ejecutar la lógica necesaria para que según los valores ingresados, puedas hacer la consulta en la base de datos y traer lo que necesitas para luego mostrar los resultados por la app

Comment: No se hacer que los checkbox cuando busque un alumno se marquen

Comment: Hola Xstrick23, si solo te falta que se marquen los ""checkBox" puedes usar: **entornosDeDesarrolloCheckBox.setSelected( true );**